# [Python][SQL Machine Learning Services] Cannot install XGBoost on my SQL instance

Tags: python, sql, machine-learning, xgboost, microsoft-machine-learning-server

I am trying to find a solution to my problem. We are trying to install XGBoost package on our MS SQL 2018 and we are facing this problem:

[Error Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiBCP.png)

The error (Błąd ogólny sieci. Zajrzyj do dokumentacji sieci.) is EN is 'General network error. See your network documentation.'. We managed to install other packages, there's only problem with this one. Any ideas what we can try to do different?

Installation is by default code:

```
import sqlmlutils
connection = sqlmlutils.ConnectionInfo(server="name,port", database="dbname", uid="accname", pwd="accpwd")
sqlmlutils.SQLPackageManager(connection).install("XGBoost")
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the driver worked for me.

```
connection = sqlmlutils.ConnectionInfo(driver='{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}',server="server_name", database="db_name")
sqlmlutils.SQLPackageManager(connection).install("xgboost")
```